# horizontal scrollbar for multiple items navigating through next/previous button in react

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, carousel, slick.js

I needed to add a horizontal slider to my 300 divs and can extend. However, there are third party slider i.e. `react-slick` but I can't use it because of CSS and other conflicts and also, my senior is not willing to use it.

Actually, I wanted the same functionality for **Uneven sets (infinite)** in this link: [react-slick examples](http://neostack.com/opensource/react-slick). I have used previous code for vertical slider:

```
<div className="md-grid" style={{ maxHeight: '300px', overflowY: 'scroll', width: '100%' }}>

    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">asd</div>
    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">dsad</div>
    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">dsa</div>
    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">asd</div>
    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">asddf</div>
    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">dsf</div>
    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">dsfsdf</div>
    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">sdfsf</div>
    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">sdf</div>
    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">ewr</div>
    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">asd</div>
    <div className="md-cell md-cell--3">jhg</div>
    ....... 
    .......
</div>
```

I wanted such result in the image below (consider multiple items or divs):
[image: resultant]

This is creating a vertical scrollbar but this is not I am looking for. Actually, I am using `react-md` ([react-md](https://react-md.mlaursen.com/)) and it does not have such type of carousel.

As, I am using `react`, I can't use jQuery. I am stuck.

Thanks

Comment: Just because you are using react doesn't mean you _cant_ use jquery. It's not recommended, but there's nothing in the library that will prevent you from doing so

Comment: `div` is styled by default as a block item with 100% width. So even though in your code all the `div`s are on the same line, they will be rendered in a stack. Are you styling your divs so that they are inline elements or floating? And you may need to apply `whitespace: nowrap` to `.md-grid` to prevent wrapping to the next line.

Comment: yes, i am using react-md builtin classes for it. i.e. react-md grid system. All divs are md-cell md-cell--3 and all are floated left by default. I wanted two rows that will slide to next 2 rows of data and so on

Comment: I have designed such divs and it is grown downwards. All I wanted those to be shown on 2 rows by pressing Next / Previous icon just like the react-slick example, i have mentioned above. Thanks